# Monte-Carlo Simulation of expected tosses for two consecutive heads in python

Tags: python, montecarlo

The expected number of tosses to get two heads in a row is 6. However on executing the below simulation of multiple runs of this experiment, I get a different plot from that expected. Could you help me identify the error in the logic?
Thanks

Code to simulate tosses and check at when two consecutive heads are encountered repeated 10000 times:

```
import random
def toss():
    return random.randint(0, 1)

expected_tosses=list()
for test in range(10000):
    a=toss()
    for i in range(2,100):
        b=toss()
        if a and b:
            expected_tosses.append(i)
            break
        a=b

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(expected_tosses, range(1,10)) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram of number of tosses to get two consecutive heads]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A: Some subtle error in the code

You are changing the statistics by limiting your upper-loop. Use an infinite loop instead.

The code then looks like the following which should be more precise:

```
import random
def toss():
    return random.randint(0, 1)

expected_tosses=list()
for test in range(10000):
    a=toss()

    i = 2
    while True:
        b=toss()
        if a and b:
            expected_tosses.append(i)
            break
        a=b
        i+=1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(sum(expected_tosses) / float(len(expected_tosses)))
plt.hist(expected_tosses, range(1,10))
plt.show()
```

#### B: Interpretation of the output

**The results are okay!**

I introduced a *calculation of the mean* of tosses needed (in the code above) and print it out. You will see, that the means looks like what you expected!

Some example output (we don't use a seed so results will differ each run):

```
5.9941
```

**Just to be clear:** The mean does not tell you that much about the *shape of the histogram*. Maybe this is the source of your confusion (having a near-minimum at 6 in your plot).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The error in the code is okay, was neglecting number of tosses greater than 100 as I knew those would be rare events, but should have implemented an infinite loop.
The mean does give the average value of the number of tosses required, but shouldn't the mode of the distribution be 6 for a large number of experiments, as there should be more occurrences of the number of tosses to be 6.

Comment: @naman No. the histogram is expected to be decreasing monotonically which is also observed. You don't see this because you give some arbitrarily bin-param to plt.hist. This behaviour is a result of the process-like nature and because we are stopping immediately after reaching the goal (= more positive observations for shorter sequences).

Comment: Ok, yes. I get the error in my interpretation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to simulate N consecutive heads:

```
import numpy as np

def toss1():
    return np.random.randint(0, 2)

def headN(N):
    # expected number of tosses 
    # to get N consecutive heads
    i = 0
    temp = [0]*N
    while np.sum(temp)<N:
        temp[i%N] = toss1()
        i += 1
    return i
```